# Java PDF Stamper writing below checkbox (text being covered by checkbox)

Tags: java, checkbox, itext, pdfstamper

Im trying to write to an existing pdf using the java pdf stamper, but for some reason there is a certain checkbox in the pdf that the text appears to be drawn under.

Code for Reading pdf:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(Testing.getImagePath() + "form.pdf");
File dir = new File(Testing.getResourcePath() + id + "/");
String destination = Testing.getResourcePath() + id + "form" + id + ".pdf";
File exist = new File(destination);

dir.mkdirs();
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(destination));
stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
PdfContentByte over;
over = stamper.getOverContent(1);
```

Code for Drawing text:

```
over.beginText();
over.setFontAndSize(bf, 11);
over.setTextMatrix(169, 322);
over.showText("X");
over.endText();
```

Comment: Where do you get over from?

Comment: Updated code. Let me know if I need to add any other code.

Comment: looking good so far. Placing an X at the location of the checkbox (only it appears under) sound a lot like you want to SELECT that checkbox?

Comment: Yeah, the goal is to fill out an existing pdf and I want to check the checkbox but the only way I know how to do this is by covering it with an "X"

Comment: AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields(); is your friend for this

Comment: Will this allow me to check the checkbox, if so how do I reference certain checkboxes through code?

Comment: yes it does see answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off:

Iterate over the FormFields in your PDF and find out the valid values to set:

```
        AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
        for(Entry<String, Item> field : form.getFields().entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(field.getKey() + ": " + field.getValue());
            String[] values = form.getAppearanceStates(field.getKey());
            StringJoiner sb = new StringJoiner(",");
            for (String value : values) {
                sb.add(value);
            }
            System.out.println("Possible Options: " + sb.toString());
        }
```

Now you should be able to select the checkbox by setting it's allowed value:

```
        form.setField("myCheckbox", "myYesValue");
```

Comment: Where did you get your AcroFields from? From the Stamper / the writer or from the reader (in which case they'd be read-only). Share the code in an edit to your question?

Comment: yeah I used different code to output the id's from the pdf, and was reading from the reader instead of the stamper. Got it to work, Thanks!